# Does BeanShell Sampler support an http request and tcp response in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

in Jmeter, i want to add a beanshell sampler, which sends http get request and waits for tcp response. is it possible? if no, are there any other methods?

Answer (score 0):

1. Beanshell Sampler supports everything which you're capable of implementing in [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/) language so you're limited only by your imagination and/or skills
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language instead of Beanshell](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so if you're at early stages of JMeter scripting assessment consider switching to JSR223 Sampler and Groovy language, it's better choice from at least performance perspective
3. As per [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) HTTP is an application level protocol (level 7) and TCP is a transport level protocol (level 4) hence any HTTP response will be TCP response (using TCP protocol as underlying transport) so you will get a TCP response in any case. So it makes sense to send a HTTP request using [TCP Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler) (or [HTTP Raw Request](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-http-raw-request-sampler-when-and-how-to-use-it) sampler), this way you will "wait" for a TCP response.